# Where Are Wireless Passwords Stored on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, security, wireless-networking

After the Snow Leopard update I can't connect to my home wifi router.

I removed it from Network Preferences and from Keychain but when I reconnect it will not ask me for the password.

All other wireless networks that I had configured previous to the update still work and all other computers work with my home router (mine did before the update).

I want to find the file where those password are stored to check its permissions or remove it and have the computer ask me for the password again to hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that the password was both in the Login Keychain as well as in the System Keychain.  I've removed it from both and now it asks for the password at the office.  I will see if this fixes the problem at home tonight.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, Keychain Access shows the *login* keychain. If the sidebar does not show any other keychains to choose from, then hit Command-K (menu View » Show Keychains) to see more choices.

On my Mac, both the *login* keychain and the *system* keychain show the same *AirPort Network password*, though the latter is a few years older. The first seems to be used by name and the latter by MAC-address. When looking at the Access Control to see which application can access the passphrase, then one sees some differences as well. But for another Wifi network I only have an entry in the *login* keychain. (Maybe the *system* keychain was used in previous versions of Mac OS X, but is still used if no entry in *login* is found?) I guess deleting all that matches indeed seems the best thing to do.

(As a side note: when one has mounted some network drive with limited credentials, and one wants to change that credentials even when the old ones are still valid, then one also needs to search in the *system* keychain, not in the *login* keychain.)

Comment: Yes, this issue was cause by the snow leopard upgrade.  After removing  the access point password from both System and Login keychains the system asked for the password again and it worked correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: In Lion, I can confirm the passwords are there.

Answer (score 7):

Check in **Keychain**. All the systems passwords should be there. I know it's not what you want to hear, but I doubt the passwords are stored anywhere else; that's the purpose of the Keychain. I haven't heard of any replacement for it being used in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

In Leopard the wireless passwords are stored in your Keychain, but from what you are saying, it sounds like this may have changed.